# How to join two table with repository and service pattern

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, join, n-tier-architecture, irepository

Greatings,

My project designed base on N-Tier Architecture. There are Core, Repository and Service layers.I have to many tables to join each other.And I would like to use Linq to support multiple sql database.

Here is my IRepository interface;

```
public interface INodeRepository :IGenericRepository<Node>
{

    Task<IEnumerable<Node>> GetAllAsync();


}
```

I am not sure that " Task<IEnumerable> GetAllAsync(); " this method is right.

Here is the Repository

```
public class NodeRepository : GenericRepository<Node>, INodeRepository
{
    public NodeRepository(AppDbContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Node>> GetAll()
    {
        return await _context.Nodes.Join()
    }

}
```

I actually dont even know how to fill it.I will also make a implementation to my Iservice.

Any help ?

Comment: From your method name and the type of return value, I think you want to select  all items and do `join` between tables. So you can try to use `.Include(xxx)` to do `join`. Because this method return `Task<xxx>`, So you need to use async  method, you can try `...ToListAsync()` to select all items.

Comment: I will also put some condition, so I should put (Expression<Func<Node> predicate>) right ?

Comment: yes, You can put func<> in `.include()`.